using eval() inside function with input of function as part of string
I have this code:
def system(into):
    global sys
    x = into
    sis = [eval(i) for i in sys]
    return sis

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys = ['x[0]+x[1]','2*x[0]-3*x[1]']

I would like to be able to evaluate this system of equation when I execute the system() function with the input into. But I am getting this error: NameError: name 'x' is not defined.
How could I solve this?

just a note that sys is an important package name.

Does this answer your question? Python: How to let eval() see local variables?

Why does system use a global variable sys and ignore its argument? (x = into would be unnecessary, but you don't use x or into.)

And one more further point, if (as it looks like) sys is defined in the global scope and you don't need the expression global sys, because you won't change it in your function. The Python interpreter will find it automatically

@chepner They're trying to use x and thus into. That's what the question is about.

You can explicitly pass the list of x values in eval function.Also,Do not use sys for naming variable,sys is in-built python module.Well it does not cause an issue untill or unless you explicitly import that package but this is not a good practice.
Below is corrected code.
def system(into):
    global sys
    x = into
    sis = [eval(i, {'x': x}) for i in sys] ## pass explicitly 
    return sis

if __name__ == "__main__":
     sys = ['x[0]+x[1]', '2*x[0]-3*x[1]']

